# How to smoothly execute mulitple Selenium scripts on a single machine at a given time

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I execute automation Selenium Scripts on remote machine which is set to perform 5 jobs at a time (5 scripts can be executed at a time by instantiating 5 browser instances).But everytime atleast 1 or 2 random scripts fail with random errors such as null pointer exception, Element not visible or not able to click the element. But it won't happen if only 3 jobs are run at a time. What's the best way i can prevent the scripts from failing.

Comment: best practise says that if u have 4 core machine then run 3 tests parallely and leave 1 core to perform background processes. try that and see if it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

very vague question. Cant really comment on why they are failing without seeing the implementation of classes.

It can happen for a lot of things including latency in network when you are running 5 instances. If that is the case you might considering using selenium grid and distribute your tests across 2 or more nodes in each of which you can run 3 instances.